# agregar elementos a un array

Tags: javascript, array

Necesito generar una función que asigne una beca a los alumnos que cumplan determinada condición, la idea es tratar de utilizar solo arrays, no objetos. Se preguntan los datos por pantalla y si cumple la condición se agrega al array becados[] y se muestra su nombre pero al no poder verlo no estoy seguro que se este agregando...
cual seria la forma mas eficiente de hacerlo? y como puedo recorrer para poder ver el nombre?

```
     function asignaBeca(){
        
        let matriculados = 2;       //Cantidad de vueltas del for
        var num_becas = 3;         //Becas disponibles
        var becados = [];

        //Datos del alumno
        var alumno = {
            nombre: undefined,
            edad: undefined,
            titulo: undefined,
             };

       //Pido los datos del alumno

            for (var i=0; i<matriculados; i++){

                alumno.nombre = window.prompt("Nombre: "+(i+1));
                edad = window.prompt("edad: "+(i+1));
                titulo = window.prompt("Titulo: "+(i+1));

                    if(edad>17 && titulo == "si"){         
                      
                        becados.push(alumno);
                        num_becas--;
                   
                     //Ver nombre del alumno becado:

                       for (let k=0; k<becados.length;k++){
                           console.log(k+ " : "+ becados[k]);
                       }

        
            }


        }

        
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente estás usando objetos. Esto es la declaración de un objeto:

```
var alumno = {
  nombre: undefined,
  edad: undefined,
  titulo: undefined,
};
```

Por otro lado, tu código tiene un fallo típico en gente con poca experiencia, pero una vez que te das cuenta de él no sueles volver a repetirlo (o, si lo haces, lo detectas rápido). Así que vamos a verlo con tu código, añadiendo unas pocas líneas:

```js
function asignaBeca(){
        
  let matriculados = 2;       //Cantidad de vueltas del for
  var num_becas = 3;         //Becas disponibles
  var becados = [];

  //Datos del alumno
  var alumno = {
    nombre: undefined,
    edad: undefined,
    titulo: undefined,
  };

 //Pido los datos del alumno

  for (var i=0; i<matriculados; i++){

    alumno.nombre = window.prompt("Nombre: "+(i+1));
    edad = window.prompt("edad: "+(i+1));
    titulo = window.prompt("Titulo: "+(i+1));

    if(edad>17 && titulo == "si"){         

      becados.push(alumno);
      num_becas--;

     //Ver nombre del alumno becado:
      console.log("Listado:");
      for (let k=0; k<becados.length;k++){
        console.log(k+ " : "+ becados[k].nombre);
      }
    }
  }
}
asignaBeca();
```

El problema es que estás reusando el mismo objeto alumno una y otra vez, con lo que todas los elementos añadidos en el array son el mismo y tendrán el valor de la última vez que se editen sus campos.

Por tanto la solución es crear un nuevo objeto en cada iteración:

```js
function asignaBeca(){
        
  const matriculados = 2;       //Cantidad de vueltas del for
  let num_becas = 3;         //Becas disponibles
  const becados = [];

 //Pido los datos del alumno
  for (let i = 0; i < matriculados; i++){
    const alumno = {
      nombre: window.prompt("Nombre: "+(i+1)),
      edad: window.prompt("edad: "+(i+1)),
      titulo: window.prompt("Titulo: "+(i+1)),
    };
    if (alumno.edad > 17 && alumno.titulo == "si"){         
      becados.push(alumno);
      num_becas--;
    }
  }
  console.log("Listado:");
  becados.forEach((becado, index) => {
    console.log((index + 1) + " : " + becado.nombre);
  });
}
asignaBeca();
```

Comment: Genial Pablo, gracias.